# How can I fill an array with user input in case of numbers c#

Tags: c#, arrays

Ok guys, im just starting C# and trying to transition from the basic side of C++. And i don`t know how to fill array list from user input into class.
This how my code looks like:

```
namespace L1
{
    public class Users
    {
        private int username;


        public Users(string username)
        {
            this.username = username;    
        }

        public string Takename() { return username; }    
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Users> users = new List<Users>();
            for(int i=1; i<=4; i++)
            {
               Console.Write("Enter username: ");
               Users user = new Users();
               user.username= Console.Readline();
               users.Add(user);
            }      
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: `private int username;` is the first problem. That should be `private string username;` Read the error message that the compiler is giving you. The second problem is that you assign to it outside the class, use the constructor that initializes the field.

Comment: @manaxi Did my answer solve your problem? Is so can you accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what the issues you are facing are but the following may help you:

```
// Renamed to User as we are representing only one user
public class User
{
    // Renamed from userName to Name
    // Made a string to be consistent with the constructor
    // Made it a public property
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public User(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string TakenName() { return Name; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<User> users = new List<User>();

        // for loops in c# typically are zero based
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter Name: ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            User user = new User(name);
            users.Add(user);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An explaination of why you changed name for class Users to User might be helpful too

Answer (score 0):

Your "username" property is an `int` when it should be a `string`.

Also, the scope of that property is private and can only be modified within the class's methods.

So either set the scope to public, or simply use:

```
User user = new Users(Console.ReadLine());
```

Here is the fixed code based on what I've told you:

```
namespace L1
{
    public class Users
    {
        private string username;


        public Users(string username)
        {
            this.username = username;    
        }

        public string Takename() { return username; }    
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Users> users = new List<Users>();
            for(int i=1; i<=4; i++)
            {
               Console.Write("Enter username: ");
               Users user = new Users(Console.Readline());
               users.Add(user);
            }      
        }               
    }
}
```